# Calculate price depending on multiple variables (range, increments, tier)

Tags: javascript

I have a pricing calculator that needs to take into account these variables based on user input: price tier, price range and price increments. Each tier leads to a different price range and a different price increment.

The calculator should take into account a specific "contact number", like 10k, 50k, and so on. Let's take for example 10000 contacts. These can be split by market tier (starter, pro, enterprise), by range (how many contacts should cost 0 USD, 50 USD and so on) and by increments (1k increments for starter, 5k increments for pro and 10k increments for enterprise).

For example if I have 10k contacts that are included in the market tier Starter, and have 1k increments, I'll need to have the sum 390 USD:

```
0 -> 1000 = 0 USD
1000 -> 2000 = 50 USD
2000 -> 3000 = 50 USD
3000 -> 4000 = 45 USD
4000 -> 5000 = 45 USD
5000 -> 6000 = 40 USD
6000 -> 7000 = 40 USD
7000 -> 8000 = 40 USD
8000 -> 9000 = 40 USD
9000 -> 10000 = 40 USD
total = 390 USD
```

If I have 10k contacts, and use as market tier Pro and their corresponding ranges, I'll have increments of 5k, and the sum should be 500 USD. And so on for pro with 10K increments.

```
// this is the first tier with prices for each range; 
let marketingStarter = [{
    1000: {
      usd: 0,
      eur: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    3000: {
      usd: 50,
      eur: 46,
    },
  },
  {
    5000: {
      usd: 45,
      eur: 41,
    },
  },
  {
    7000: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
  {
    9000: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
  {
    9001: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
];

[...]

const priceRangeStarter = [1000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 9000, 9001];

// second and third price range
const priceRangePro = [2000, 2200, 42000, 62000, 82000, 82001];
const priceRangeEnt = [10000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 500000, 500001];

// price should be calculated in increments of 1k for starter, 5k for pro, and 10k for Ent;
const priceIncrements = [1000, 5000, 10000];
```

This is what I tried:

```
function marketingPricing() {
  let currency = "usd";
  let contacts = 10000;
  let pricePerContact,
    sum = 0,
    totalPrice;

  for (let i = 0; i < priceRangeStarter.length; i++) {
    if (contacts >= priceRangeStarter[i]) {
     
     // get price per contact from array
      pricePerContact = marketingStarter[i][priceRangeStarter[i]][currency];
      // 0 - 1000 = 0 USD
      // 1000 - 3000 = 50 USD
      // 3000 - 5000 = 45 USD
      // 5000 - 7000 = 40 USD
      // 7000 - 9000 = 40 USD
      // 9001 --- 40 USD   
      
      // calculate rest of contacts
      contacts = contacts - priceRangeStarter[i];
      // 1: 9000;
      // 2: 6000;
      // 3: 1000;
      
      // price is per 1K
      totalPrice = pricePerContact * (priceRangeStarter[i] / priceIncrements[0]);
      // 1: 50 USD * 1000 / 1000 = 50; (should be 0)
      // 2: 45 USD * 3000 / 1000 = 135; (should be 90)
      // 3: 40 USD * 1000 / 1000 = 40; (correct)
            
      sum = sum + totalPrice;
      
        // 0 -> 1000 = 0 USD
      // 1000 -> 2000 = 50 USD
      // 2000 -> 3000 = 50 USD
      // 3000 -> 4000 = 45 USD
      // 4000 -> 5000 = 45 USD
      // 5000 -> 6000 = 40 USD
      // 6000 -> 7000 = 40 USD
      // 7000 -> 8000 = 40 USD
      // 8000 -> 9000 = 40 USD
      // 9000 -> 10000 = 40 USD
      // total = 390 USD      

    } else {
      pricePerContact = marketingStarter[i][priceRangeStarter[i]][currency];

      totalPrice = pricePerContact * (contacts / priceIncrements[0]);
      contacts = 0;
      sum = sum + totalPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. You can find a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rnef1hdo/6/

Comment: Can you please explain the problem which are facing with your current code. It will be more useful if you can add some use case .

Comment: indeed, show us an expected output please.. as in the `correct` sum example with given input

Comment: The problem is that the sum is incorrect. I've added comments for each loop, and the expected output. I can't figure out how to include the priceIncrements array to get the correct sum.

Comment: i have a feeling part of the problem is that you have some of the variables outside the forloop and are using them like they are part of it(and linking logic happens).. gonna take a while to prove it with the answer tho

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita check my answer

Comment: I've added more explanations, I was so tired yesterday I couldn't think straight, I didn't even realised I didn't said what I want to calculate and how. Really sorry for the bad explanation!

Comment: ok i edited my answer to factor in `increment` @GeorgeGrigorita

Comment: ohh I am just assuming im counting in increments until i reached the highest contact tier.. putting contacts as a parameter now

Comment: `If I have 10k contacts, and use as market tier Pro and their corresponding ranges, I'll have increments of 5k, and the sum should be 500 USD` HOW?? the range that gets > 0 usd is over 10k, so just like u did the 390 example, EXPLAIN the 500 example PLEASE @GeorgeGrigorita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more days of struggle I found a solution to get the right results using the original solution. I admit that I should have been better at explaining the problem.

What I did different: I've added the `previousRange` to be able to calculate the paid contacts number. I've added `Math.ceil` for the last contacts, to round up the final price. And the most important step, that was also the problem solver: I've added a new variable `priceRangeInterval` with the range differences. These are also the paid contacts for each step in the for loop. So I replaced the `if` condition in the `for loop` from `priceRange` to `priceRangeInterval`. Then everything made sense, and worked as it should.

This is the solution:

```
const priceRangeStarter = [1000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 9000, 9001];
const priceRangePro = [2000, 22000, 42000, 62000, 82000, 82001];
const contactsBand = [1000, 5000, 10000];

const priceRangeIntervalStarter = 2000;
const priceRangeIntervalPro = 20000;
const priceRangeIntervalEnt = [10000, 40000, 50000, 100000, 400000];

function marketingPricing() {
  let currency = "usd";
  let priceRange = priceRangePro;
  let marketTier = marketingPro;
  let priceRangeInterval = priceRangeIntervalPro;
  let contacts = 98000;
  let contactsBandTier = contactsBand[1];
  let pricePerContact,
    sum = 0,
    totalPrice;

  for (let i = 0; i < priceRange.length; i++) {
    if (priceRangeInterval === priceRangeIntervalEnt) {
      priceRangeInterval = priceRangeIntervalEnt[i];
    }

    if (contacts >= priceRangeInterval && i < (priceRange.length - 1)) {
      // get price per contact from array
      pricePerContact = marketTier[i][priceRange[i]][currency];

      // calculate rest of contacts
      let previousPriceRange = 0;

      if (i != 0) {
        previousPriceRange = priceRange[i - 1];
      }
      contacts = contacts - (priceRange[i] - previousPriceRange);
      totalPrice = pricePerContact * ((priceRange[i] - previousPriceRange) / contactsBandTier);
      sum = sum + totalPrice;
    } else {
      pricePerContact = marketTier[i][priceRange[i]][currency];
      totalPrice = pricePerContact * Math.ceil(contacts / contactsBandTier);
      contacts = 0;
      sum = sum + totalPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54pkgvd9/1/

Thank you to all that took time to try to understand and help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realise what you INTEND for this to be.. the `sum` is the SUM of every increment of 1000 **WITH** taking into account the tiers and whatnot

EDIT: It seems you want the increment changing as well.. well here you go
EDIT 2: It seems I answered what you wanted but by nature what you want is flaud?? idk yet

```js
//solution function
//default contacts is 1000, default increment is 1000
function marketPricing(market,currency,increment,contacts){
  contacts=contacts||10000 //default contacts 1000
  var prices=market.map((a,i)=>[Object.keys(market[i])[0],Object.values(a)[0][currency]]) //makes the info off of the tier data (0 is range, 1 is tier)
  //console.log(prices) //un-comment the beginning of this line to show what prices is
  var i=0, sum=0, tier=0
  while(i<=contacts&&prices.length){ //loop stops increment reaches contacts OR market tiers are saturated
    sum+=prices[0][1]
    if(i>=prices[0][0]){prices.splice(0,1)}
    i+=increment||1000 //default increment is 1000
  }
  return sum
}

//examples
console.log("the answer to your example is "+marketPricing(marketingStarter,"usd")) //your example
console.log("if we use eur currency instead, the answer is "+marketPricing(marketingStarter,"eur")) //different currency
console.log("if we use usd currency in separate market, the answer is "+marketPricing(marketingPro,"usd",5000)) //different market
```

```html
<script>
//here is where I place the different market arrays
let marketingStarter = [{
    1000: {
      usd: 0,
      eur: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    3000: {
      usd: 50,
      eur: 46,
    },
  },
  {
    5000: {
      usd: 45,
      eur: 41,
    },
  },
  {
    7000: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
  {
    9000: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
  {
    9001: {
      usd: 40,
      eur: 36,
    },
  },
];
let marketingPro = [{
    2000: {
      usd: 0,
      eur: 0,
      gbp: 0,
      aud: 0,
      jpy: 0,
      sgd: 0,
      cop: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    22000: {
      usd: 250,
      eur: 230,
      gbp: 210,
      aud: 375,
      jpy: 30000,
      sgd: 350,
      cop: 750000,
    },
  },
  {
    42000: {
      usd: 225,
      eur: 205,
      gbp: 185,
      aud: 325,
      jpy: 27000,
      sgd: 315,
      cop: 675000,
    },
  },
  {
    62000: {
      usd: 200,
      eur: 180,
      gbp: 165,
      aud: 290,
      jpy: 24000,
      sgd: 280,
      cop: 600000,
    },
  },
  {
    82000: {
      usd: 175,
      eur: 160,
      gbp: 145,
      aud: 255,
      jpy: 21000,
      sgd: 245,
      cop: 525000,
    },
  },
  {
    82001: {
      usd: 150,
      eur: 135,
      gbp: 125,
      aud: 220,
      jpy: 18000,
      sgd: 210,
      cop: 450000,
    },
  },
];
</script>
```